# Oracle APEX - APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, apex

I have a process running On Submit.

At the end of the process, I am trying to update the session state of an item :P2_CASE_ID.

I am trying to assign it the value of a variable calculated in the PL\SQL.

My code at the end setting the session state is as below:

```
APEX_DEBUG.INFO(p_message => 'ABOUT TO CHANGE VALUE OF P2_CASE_ID, BEFORE:  ' || :P2_CASE_ID);
APEX_DEBUG.INFO(p_message => 'CHANGING P2_CASE_ID TO HAVE THE VALUE OF case_ids:  ' || case_ids);

APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('P2_CASE_ID',RTRIM(case_ids , ','));

APEX_DEBUG.INFO(p_message => 'CHANGED VALUE OF P2_CASE_ID, AFTER:  ' || :P2_CASE_ID);
```

When I check the debug logs, the session state hasn't changed.

```
select * from APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGES WHERE MESSAGE like '%P2_CASE_ID%'
ORDER BY MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Output from DEBUG:

```
> ABOUT TO CHANGE VALUE OF P2_CASE_ID, BEFORE:  2003,2004
> CHANGING P2_CASE_ID TO HAVE THE VALUE OF case_ids: 2006,2007,2008,2009
> Session State: P2_CASE_ID=>2006, 2007, 2008, 2009
> CHANGED VALUE OF P2_CASE_ID, AFTER: 2003,2004
```

The debug line starting "Session State" is not one of mine, so assume it is an output of the APEX_UTIL function to set the session state.

Answer (score 0):

Use `APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_STATE` to check if it is in session state. Mixing bind variable syntax with set/get session state in the same process is not a good practice.

But... there should be no need to use `APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE` within the context of your application.

```
:P2_CASE_ID := RTRIM(case_ids , ',');
```

Will work just as well and it's less typing :)

Comment: I used set session state because when creating a new record, it’s the only way it would work.  When I edit a record - set session state doesn’t work.  I started out using bind variable syntax.  Didn’t work for brand new records.

Comment: I'd have to see in detail how you're doing it in order to comment - feel free to provide details, maybe in another question. There should be no difference between set_session_state and bind variable syntax. I've written many different apps and I only used it once for a single app.

Comment: Just curious - did you actually check using get_session_state in the apex debug call  ? The point I was trying to make is that you set it using set_session_state but you then use bind var syntax in the debug call to check for the actual value. Try using get_session_state instead.

Comment: You know what the issue was.  I pass a page item value to P2_EDIT_MODE, which is either CREATE (for new items) or EDIT when entering from other places.  I had a "Before Request" process running for when it was in EDIT mode, to reload the values from the database!!  So this must be running AFTER I set the values in the process above.  Interestingly I tried to not run this "Before Regions " process when a particular button was pressed, but at this point in the processing you cant seem to get a hold of the REQUEST value.  I am doing a SUBMIT to do a file upload